# how can i print subscription from object

Tags: php

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#997 ▼
  #total: 575
  #lastPage: 58
  #items: Collection {#1007 ▼
    #items: array:10 [▼
      0 => WorkableInterviews {#1008 ▶}
      1 => WorkableInterviews {#1009 ▶}
      2 => WorkableInterviews {#1010 ▶}

    ]
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "https://localhost/employer/interviews/MQ=="
  #query: array:1 [▼
    "subscription" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "prepaidxxxx"
    ]
  ]
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

my object is like this, I want to print this section query: array:1 subscription, How can do this

Comment: echo $obj->query["subscription"][0] ;

Comment: `query` is a protected variable. So you cannot.